# Problem running JasperReport 6.6.0 with Tomcat 8 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unresolved external reference

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports, tomcat8

I'm running JasperReport Library 6.6.0, openjdk 1.8.0_372, Tomcat 7 and PHP/JAVA Bridge on a Centos 7 server. Everything is working just fine.

I need to move it to a new server Rocky Linux 9.2 and Tomcat 8. I installed the same openjdk version 1.8.0_372. I copied all JasperReport 6.6.0 files from the old server to the new one.

When I try to run a report, I'm getting the following error message. I'm not able to figure out what could cause it. Despite the fact that this is a different Linux version and a different Tomcat version, all the rest is identical since I copied all files from the old server.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unresolved external reference: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ReferenceMap. -- Unable to call the method, see the README section "Java platform issues" for details and DO NOT REPORT THIS PROBLEM TO THE PHP/Java Bridge MAILING LIST!
    at php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.getUnresolvedExternalReferenceException(JavaBridge.java:422)
    at php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.Invoke(JavaBridge.java:1055)
    at php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:417)
    at php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500)
    at php.java.bridge.http.ContextRunner.run(ContextRunner.java:145)
    at php.java.bridge.ThreadPool$Delegate.run(ThreadPool.java:60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. The file commons-collections-3.2.2.jar was missing.